# Time difference between two times

Tags: android, time

I want to display the difference between two times in hh:mm format.

The first time is from a database and the second time is the system time. Time difference is updated every second.

How can I do that?

Currently I'm  using two manual time if this works perfectly then I implement it into my apps.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView mytext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Timer updateTimer = new Timer();
        updateTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    TextView txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                    Date date1 = format.parse("08:00:12 pm");
                    Date date2 = format.parse("05:30:12 pm");
                    long mills = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                    Log.v("Data1", ""+date1.getTime());
                    Log.v("Data2", ""+date2.getTime());
                    int hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                    int mins = (int) (mills % (1000*60*60));

                    String diff = hours + ":" + mins; // updated value every1 second
                    txtCurrentTime.setText(diff);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the one from the database a String or Date instance?

Comment: What is the magnitude of the difference (seconds, milliseconds, days...)?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: @assylias i need in hh:mm format 
for example 11:05 am - 12:30 pm = 01:25

Comment: @JustDanyul String instance

Comment: @Egor no i dont how to start :( plz help me

Comment: How would you take into account different locales?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To Calculate the difference between two dates you could try something like:

```
long millis = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
int hours = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins = (int) ((millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60);

String diff = hours + ":" + mins;
```

To update the Time Difference every second you can make use of Timer.

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer();
updateTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            long mills = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                int hours = millis/(1000 * 60 * 60);
                 int mins = (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;

                 String diff = hours + ":" + mins; // updated value every1 second
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}, 0, 1000); // here 1000 means 1000 mills i.e. 1 second
```

Edit : Working Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtCurrentTime;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        Timer updateTimer = new Timer();
        updateTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                    Date date1 = format.parse("08:00:12 pm");
                    Date date2 = format.parse("05:30:12 pm");
                    long mills = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                    Log.v("Data1", ""+date1.getTime());
                    Log.v("Data2", ""+date2.getTime());
                    int hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                    int mins = (int) (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;

                    String diff = hours + ":" + mins; // updated value every1 second
                    txtCurrentTime.setText(diff);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: here run method will execute every second, so whatever you want to update or calculate you can write inside it..

Comment: I have checked the code and fixed the problem. Sorry for late reply! Now the code is working.

Comment: yaa the code is working perfectly but still it not update every second ..
plz try to solve it...

Comment: i need another favor from you.
 can you update this code now I need to perform my task with system time and manual time. 
and then update the difference every second.

like 
System time :- 01:00:00 pm
manual time :- 12:50:00 pm
ans :- 00:10 when clock reach 01:00:00 pm
then   00:11 when clock reach 01:01:00 pm
then   00:12 when clock reach 01:02:00 pm
and so on plz help

Comment: let me try again , your code is perfect working for me but i need it to little update. My task is to get the difference between two time 1st time is manual and 2nd time is system time.
if i set manual time 12:50:00 pm and system time 01:00:00 pm then i need answer 00:10, after 1 min i need the answer 00:11, and so on .

Comment: @SanoberMalik Just a little tip: By convention, variable names should start with a lower case character.

Comment: It give some wrong values like I am from India's time is 30 min ahead but it gives -11:-30

Answer (score 10):

finally did it yuppiiieee ...

```
package com.timedynamicllyupdate;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView current;
    private TextView txtCurrentTime;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread myThread = null;
        Runnable myRunnableThread = new CountDownRunner();
        myThread= new Thread(myRunnableThread);   
        myThread.start();

        current= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current);
    }


    public void doWork() 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");

                    txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);

                    Date systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    String myDate = sdf.format(systemDate);
//                  txtCurrentTime.setText(myDate);

                    Date Date1 = sdf.parse(myDate);
                    Date Date2 = sdf.parse("02:50:00 pm");

                    long millse = Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime();
                    long mills = Math.abs(millse);

                    int Hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                    int Mins = (int) (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;
                    long Secs = (int) (mills / 1000) % 60;

                    String diff = Hours + ":" + Mins + ":" + Secs; // updated value every1 second
                    current.setText(diff);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable
    {
        // @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                try 
                {
                    doWork();
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Pause of 1 Second
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes.

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Define a formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
String inputStart = "08:00:12 pm".toUpperCase() ;
String inputStop = "05:30:12 pm".toUpperCase() ;

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" );
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( inputStart , f );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( inputStop , f );
```

> start.toString(): 20:00:12
>
> stop.toString(): 17:30:12

The `LocalTime` class works within a single generic 24-hour day. So it does not consider crossing midnight. If you want to cross over between days you should be using `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `LocalDateTime` instead, all date-time objects rather than time-of-day-only.

A [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) captures a span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Calling `toString` generates text in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. I strongly recommend using this format rather than "HH:MM:SS" format that is ambiguous with clock-time.

If you insist on using the ambiguous clock-time format, in Java 9 and later you can build that string by calling `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart`, and `toSecondsPart`.

In your example data we are moving backwards in time, going from 8 PM to 5 PM, so the result is a negative number of hours and minutes, a negative two and a half hours.

> d.toString(): PT-2H-30M

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/quitlH).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

OK I Build here Funcion for you:

```
 public void omriFunction(){
    Date Start = null;
    Date End = null;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try {
        Start = simpleDateFormat.parse(04+":"+30);
        End = simpleDateFormat.parse(06+":"+45);}
    catch(ParseException e){
        //Some thing if its not working
    }

    long difference = End.getTime() - Start.getTime();
    int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));
    int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60));
    int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
    if(hours < 0){
        hours+=24;
    }if(min < 0){
        float  newone = (float)min/60 ;
        min +=60;
        hours =(int) (hours +newone);}
    String c = hours+":"+min;
    Log.d("ANSWER",c);}
```

ANSWER :2:15; in the logcat

Comment: hi,how to get seconds in the same format like above (mins, hours)?

Answer (score 2):

The process is roughly as follows,

1. Convert your string instance to a date instance the following way

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Date date = format.parse("2011-01-03");
   ```
2. Assuming the systemTime you have is a long, representing miliseconds since the epoc, you can now do the following

   ```
   long difference = longNow - date.getTime();
   int msPerHour = 1000*60*60;
   int hours = difference/secondPerHour;
   int minutes = difference % secondPerHour;
   ```

   where `longNow` is your current variable containing system time.

Comment: finally I got it, what I really want to do thanks to every one for your suggestion, code, example and help frndzzzz...

Answer (score 1):

```
Date currentTime = parseDate("11:27:20 AM");
Date endTime = parseDate("10:30:01 AM");

if (endTime.before(currentTime))
{
    Log.e("Time :","===> is before from current time");
}

if (endTime.after(currentTime))
{
    Log.e("Time :","===> is after from current time");
}



private Date parseDate(String date)
{
    String inputFormat = "hh:mm:ss aa";
    SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.US);
    try {
        return inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys not sure what I was doing wrong , but this helped for me , hope I can help someone else out.

My min were being calculated in some float format so I used this formula

```
long Min = time %  (1000*60*60)/(60*1000);
time is my date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Tray The following code to get hour and minute different between two times:

```
private static int getHoursDiff(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
            Date d1 = c1.getTime();
            Date d2 = c2.getTime();
            long mils = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
            int hourDiff = (int) (mils / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            return hourDiff;
        }

        private static int getMinuteDiff(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
            Date d1 = c1.getTime();
            Date d2 = c2.getTime();
            long mils = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
            int minuteFor = (int) (mils / (1000 * 60) % 60);
            return minuteFor;
        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was hunting around for a way where I could get HH/MM/SS from 2 Times in Kolin and this seems like a nice way to do it.

It uses **import org.threeten.bp**

```
fun getTimedifference(startTime: LocalDateTime,  endTime: LocalDateTime): String {
        val startTimeInstant = startTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()
        val endTimeInstant = endTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()
        val duration = Duration.between(startTimeInstant, endTimeInstant)
        val days = duration.toDays()
        val hours = duration.toHours() - (days * 24)
        val min = duration.toMinutes() - (duration.toHours() * 60)
        val sec = (duration.toMillis() / 1000) - (duration.toMinutes() * 60)
        return "${hours}:${min}:${sec}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function, if you want correct time diff you must add timezone in it, this is a normal mistake.

```
fun main() {
    val format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val sdf =  SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault())
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Karachi")) //make sure to set timezone
    
    val arrivedDate = "03/15/2022 12:00:00 PM"
    val currentDate = sdf.format(cal.timeInMillis)
    
    print("Arrived time: " + arrivedDate + "\n")
    print("Current time: " + currentDate + "\n")
    
    val arrivedDateMillis = getLongDateFromString(arrivedDate, sdf) 
    val currentDateMillis = getLongDateFromString(currentDate, sdf)
   
    val diff = (currentDateMillis - arrivedDateMillis) / 1000
    
    val p1 = diff % 60
    var p2 = diff / 60  
    val p3 = p2 % 60
    val p4 = diff / 60 / 60 / 24
    p2 = p2 / 60 % 24

    print("$p4:$p2:$p3:$p1") //days:hours:minutes:seconds
   
}

fun getLongDateFromString(time: String, format: SimpleDateFormat): Long {
    try {
        val date = format.parse(time)
        return date.time

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return 0L
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use below options to get the hours and minutes difference between dates

```
val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(date1.time-date2.time)
val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(date1.time-date2.time)
```