# How to calculate a time diffrence

Tags: android, timedelta

I'm trying to calculate a simple time diffrence.
It's a simple math calculation, but i don't know how to do it.

What im trying to do is for example to calculate 23:23:20 - 23:23:10 = 00:00:10.
And I want to save the result.

My question is: how do I write the code?

**I tried this, not sure how right it is**

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+2:00"));                               Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
            date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+2:00"));
            String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15360419/4038549) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18908807/4038549).

Comment: i'll have a look, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+2:00"));
Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+3:00"));

Date date = new Date(date2.getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTimeInMillis());
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

String formattedResult = dateFormatter.format(date);
```