# Android find reaming time or deference between two times

Tags: android, performance, datetime, time

**Want to find difference between two times**
I have two times **12:16:40** and **12:16:50**.
I want difference is **10 seconds** if the difference is in minutes then display the difference in **minutes** or if the difference is in seconds then display the difference **seconds** and so on.

I want an answer like this

2 sec ago

5 mins ago

2 hours ago

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); // Hours:Minutes:Seconds
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: So you want to display a time difference expressed in milliseconds differently dependent on the size of the difference? Use some if statements to distinguish the cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time difference between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360123/time-difference-between-two-times)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This topic has been addressed *many* times already.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below code this is the example i have given you need to make changes according to your requiremnts

```
try {

                Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa",Locale.US);
                String formattedTime = df2.format(c2.getTime());
                date2 = df2.parse(formattedTime);

                long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();


                int Hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                int Minuets = (int) (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;
                int Seconds = (int) (mills/1000) % 60;

                String hr = String.format("%02d", Hours);
                String min = String.format("%02d", Minuets);
                String sec = String.format("%02d", Seconds);


                endTime = hr + ":" + min + ":" +sec; // updated value every1 second

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So for your question use below function to get answer and import below clases

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

private void cluclate()
{
    Date date1,date2;

    try {

        String  endTime;

        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.add(Calendar.HOUR,12);
        c1.add(Calendar.MINUTE,16);
        c1.add(Calendar.SECOND,40);
        SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        String formattedTime1 = df1.format(c1.getTime());
        date1 = df1.parse(formattedTime1);


        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.add(Calendar.HOUR,12);
        c2.add(Calendar.MINUTE,16);
        c2.add(Calendar.SECOND,50);
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss",Locale.US);
        String formattedTime2 = df2.format(c2.getTime());
        date2 = df2.parse(formattedTime2);


        long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();


        int Hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
        int Minuets = (int) (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;
        int Seconds = (int) (mills/1000) % 60;

        String hr = String.format("%02d", Hours);
        String min = String.format("%02d", Minuets);
        String sec = String.format("%02d", Seconds);


        endTime = hr + ":" + min + ":" +sec; // updated value every1 second

        Log.d("=============>>>>",endTime);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    /*
    your operations should do here
     */
    long secondTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long difference = secondTime - firstTime;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(difference);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMANY);
    String yourDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in a runnable, so that it keeps on checking.

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa",Locale.US);
String formattedTime = df2.format(c2.getTime());
date2 = df2.parse(formattedTime);
//date1 is the first time, date2 is current time.
long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

int Hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int Minuets = (int) (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;
int Seconds = (int) (mills/1000) % 60;

if(Hours == 0) {
    if(Minutes == 0) {
        displayString = Seconds.toString() + " ago";
    } else {
        displayString = Minutes.toString() + " ago";
    }
} else {
    displayString = Hours.toString() + " ago";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using DateUtils class.

**[getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long))**

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 50);
System.out.println(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time.getTimeInMillis(), now.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS));
```

This will also be valid if the time difference is in minutes or hours.

Comment: If i will set time 
 time.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
                        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);
                        time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

                        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                        now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
                        now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
                        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 50);

it will return in 10 hours

Comment: It depends on the date in time and now variables.