# Getting Time Difference In android from Timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp

I am saving current date in timestamp value in my firebase with below code

```
 userValues.put("p_date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

what I need to do is show a time difference between above saved value and current timestamp value, I have tried below code

```
//time ago
        String starttime = book.getP_date().toString(); //getting saved timestamp from firebase

        //current time
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String endtime = tsLong.toString();

        long diffTime = Long.parseLong(endtime) - Long.parseLong(starttime);
        String elapsedtime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(diffTime)));

        tvTimeAgo.setText(elapsedtime+"ago");
```

it is giving a result like `07:59:56 ago` shown time difference is returning wrong result also what I need to have is `0h 5min 3s ago`
how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check if this answers your question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360123/time-difference-between-two-times/15360419>?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` for formate TimeStamp as below

```
String timeHH_MM_SS = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffTime),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffTime) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffTime) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));

    tvTimeAgo.setText("Time in hh:mm:ss is: "+timeHH_MM_SS);
```